# Get text using Regular Expression

Tags: regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have the sentence as below:

`First learning of regular expression.`

And I want to extract only `First learning` and `expression` by means of regular expressions.

Where would I start/

Comment: Why use regex to match literals?

Comment: Is this sentence specific, should you match those exact words, or is it like the first second and last word in any sentence?

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are for pattern matching, which means we'd need to know a pattern that is to be matched.

If you literally just want those strings, you'd just use `First learning` and `expression` as your patterns.

As @orique says, this is kind of pointless; you don't need RegEx for that. If you want something more complicated, you'd need to explain what you're trying to match.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is not usually used to match literal text like what you're doing, but instead is used to match patterns of text. If you insist on using regex, you'll have to match the trivial expression

```
(First learning|expression)
```

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, it is unusual to match a literal string like you are asking, but more common to match patterns such as several word characters followed by a space character etc...

Here is a pattern to match several word characters (which are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and _) followed by a space, followed by several more word characters etc... It ends up capturing three groups. The first group will match the first two words, the second part the next to words, and the last part, the fifth word and the preceding space.

```
$words = "First learning of regular expression.";
preg_match(/(\w+\s\w+)\s(\w+\s\w+)(\s\w+)/, $words, $matches);
$result = matches[1]+matches[3];
```

I hope this matches your requirement.